# Disable url on an element based on the value of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that will have several rows.  In one column, there is a link (column a).  In the second column, there is the string "Yes" or "No" (column b).

If a cell in column b says "No", I want the link on the cell directly to the left of it in column a to become disabled.

I'm using `.each()` to go through each td in column b to see if the value is "Yes" or "No".  It seems as though even if the cell in column b is "Yes", it will still disable (rename) the link on the matching cell.  What am I missing?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("td.regFull").each(function () {

    console.log($(this).text());
    if($(this).text() !== 'No') {
      $('td.regLink a').replaceWith('Closed');
    }
    
  });

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Registration Open</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="regLink">
      <a href="#">Register</a>
    </td>
    <td class="regFull">
      No
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="regLink">
      <a href="#">Register</a>
    </td>
    <td class="regFull">
      Yes
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is:

in order to disable a link you may remove the href attribute.

To select all links you may reduce all to one line:

```
$("td.regFull:contains('No')").siblings('td.regLink').children('a').removeAttr('href')
```

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  
 $("td.regFull:contains('No')").siblings('td.regLink').children('a').removeAttr('href').text('Closed');

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Registration Open</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="regLink">
            <a href="#">Register</a>
        </td>
        <td class="regFull">
            No
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="regLink">
            <a href="#">Register</a>
        </td>
        <td class="regFull">
            Yes
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td class="regLink">
            <a href="#">Register</a>
        </td>
        <td class="regFull">
            No
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="regLink">
            <a href="#">Register</a>
        </td>
        <td class="regFull">
            Yes
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line

$('td.regLink a').replaceWith('Closed');

Make it as closest element

$(this).closest('td.regLink a').replaceWith('Closed');

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to trim the content of `.regFull` in the condition to remove the spaces.
2. Go up to the parent tr then select the link inside `.regLink` :

   ```
   $(this).parents('tr').find('.regLink a').replaceWith('Closed');
   ```
3. > If a cell in column b says "No", I want the link on the cell directly to the left of it in column a to become disabled.

   So you have to reverse the operator in your condition from `!==` to `===`.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("td.regFull").each(function () {

    console.log($(this).text().trim());

    if($(this).text().trim() === 'No') {
      $(this).parents('tr').find('.regLink a').replaceWith('Closed');
    }

  });

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Registration Open</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="regLink">
      <a href="#">Register</a>
    </td>
    <td class="regFull">
      No
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="regLink">
      <a href="#">Register</a>
    </td>
    <td class="regFull">
      Yes
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```